# How to format a drive with Ubuntu on it

Tags: partitioning

Is it possible to format a drive with Ubuntu on it. I've tried the gpart way and I could only get the format option for the small partition, leaving the large main partition intact. After that I could not get back in. Can I get a pdf file explaining it.

Comment: You cannot ask more than one unrelated question at a time, please open a new question for the second question.

Comment: Do you understand what formatting is, and that formatting the drive containing Ubuntu would remove Ubuntu and all of your files?  And that it cannot be done from within the operating system you are removing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't format a drive which contains the operating system doing the formatting, otherwise it would erase itself.

As @thomasrutter said, understand that formatting will wipe out EVERYTHING on that partition.

The easiest way to do it is to make a bootable Ubuntu on USB stick or CD, Ubuntu includes startup disk creator for that. When you boot your POST screen should say something along the lines press F2 or F12 for setup, Press F10 or DEL for boot order. Go to Boot Order, select the USB stick and boot into it, at the menu select Try without Installing, which will load an Ubuntu Live USB. At that point you can use GParted or Disks to erase anything your heart pleases

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to remove Ubuntu and install another OS over it, you should backup any important files/folders before you do anything with partitions.

Now that you've backed up all of your important things, insert the new OS disc/USB stick into your computer. Make sure you have the correct boot order set up. Then, when prompted about partitioning, select something that goes along these lines: "Erase Ubuntu [14.10] LTS and install [Windows 8] over it". This should remove Ubuntu easily.

If you are not planning to install another OS, try looking through your boot options to see if there is a partition manager of some sort and use that.

Also, I believe you can simply search "Uninstall Ubuntu" through the main menu, and you might be able to find something there as well.